# How to update a child of a firebase object using angularfire2

Tags: ionic3, angularfire2

[image: All i need to do is update the value of status into 1 on a button click]

All I need to do is update the value of status (highlighted child in above image )into 1 on a button click, i followed the angluarfire2 documentation on updating a list value and didn't get the expected output. 
here's the code

```
confirm(item: Item){

const items = this.db2.list('/items');
items.update(item.key, { price: 69 }).then(()=>{
  this.toast.show(`${item.name} confirmed two ! `);
  this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try this:

```js
const items = this.db2.list('/list');
items.update(item.key, { price: 69, status:1 }).then(()=>{
  this.toast.show(`${item.name} confirmed two ! `);
  this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
});
```